# Outputting XML on Java Servlet using PrintWriter

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, servlets

I have used [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/) to convert an ArrayList to XML. My code is successfully outputting XML to the Eclipse console.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder build = dFact.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = build.newDocument();

Element root = doc.createElement("Properties");
doc.appendChild(root);

for(House house : house) {

    Element Details = doc.createElement("house");
    root.appendChild(Details);

    Element location = doc.createElement("location");
    location.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(house.getLocation()));
    Details.appendChild(location);

    ...

}

 // Save the document to the disk file
TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();

// format the XML nicely
aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");

aTransformer.setOutputProperty(
        "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(System.out);
aTransformer.transform(source, result);
```

Instead of outputting this XML to the Eclipse console, I would like to print out the XML on a servlet.

I have done something similar with a jsonObject, using the following code:

```
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
...
out.print(jsonObject);
out.close();
```

But I can't seem to work out how to use this method to output my XML.

Please can someone point me in the right direction. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the `response.getOutputStream()` to write the XML to Servlet output.

```
StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(response.getOutputStream());
```

Preferably, you can use a `Writer`, the `response.getWriter()` can be used on `StreamResult`:

```
StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(response.getWriter());
```

Also, you will need to set the `Content-Type` header to `text/html; charset=UTF-8` (and provided your encoding is indeed `UTF-8`).

```
response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the content type:

```
response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8"); //you can set the encode you want to charset
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(yourXmlString);
```